# Unable to set proper routing between two networks

Tags: networking, network-manager, routing

Three boxes running three different ubuntu flavours (14.04, 14.10, 15.04). I'm trying to get all of these to talk between themselves, while being on different subnets, and I can't figure how, yet.

Problem is that my ISP provides a router for the TV, phone and internet. We cannot change the hub's lan range (192.168.2.0/24), while my lan with my own router is on 10.0.0.0/13 (and I *don't* want to change it).

Here's the setup: [image]

My ISP's hub/router is on 192.168.2.1, so that's the gw facing internet.
My own router is connected (DHCP) to this router, its LAN address is thus in 192.168.2.0/24 .

I have PC1, PC2 and PC3 in 10.0.0.0/13, going on the Net thru my own router, which is connected onto my ISP-provided router in 192.168.2.0/24. Those PCs can connect onto my 192.168.2.1.

Now, I have to connect a PC directly onto my ISP-provided router; it'll have a 192.168.2.0/24 address, and cannot see other devices into 10.0.0.0/13 . I'm not that well-versed in routing, I'm wondering what can I do to get it to see PCs onto 10.0.0.0/13 ?

Oh, and the easy way is out : I cannot add a static route on 192.168.2.1 (the ISP gateway).

Any ideas?

--Jeff

Comment: I always modify my ISP's router internal IP to suit my needs so I've never attempted this with the restrictions you state. I'll be watching this for answers though....

Comment: You might find this interessting: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/routing-2-internal-networks-878214/ post 11 may provide some clues

Comment: Elder Geek : that's what I'd done, but my ISP's router is quite dumb (or assuming most of its users are !). Not much I can change on it. First thing I'd have done would be to switch its LAN config to suit my own on 10.0.0.0/13, or add a static route on its config, but no, I can't.

Comment: I would assume you'll need a device bridging the networks, whether this be a router or a computer acting as one.

Comment: Disable firewall and NAT on your router, then create a static route in the PC on 10.0.0.0/13 network pointing to your router's WAN: `route add -net 10.0.0.0/13 gw 192.168.2.X`

Comment: This won't work, @EricCarvalho :
'code12:43:44|root@bergen:~] ifconfig eth0|grep inet|grep -v inet6<br/>
          inet addr:10.3.2.1  Bcast:10.7.255.255  Mask:255.248.0.0<br/>
[12:43:47|root@bergen:~] route add -net 10.0.0.0/13 gw 192.168.2.2<br/>
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable<br/>

Actually, I don't see why I should create a route from 10.0.0.0/13 to 192.168.2.2 as I'm already able from 10/13 to reach 192/24, but the reverse is not possible, which is my whole problem

Comment: still have issues with formatting on this board, sorry :-)

Comment: @ElderGeek : yes, that's what I wanted. I would have put all PCs onto the same router if possible, but the reason I'm putting the latest PC directly onto my ISP's one is because all the devices are too physically far from each other (different floors of the house, etc).

Comment: Regarding physical distance. Understood. On another note, You'll have better luck with formatting if you [edit] your question to add info. Comments are second class citizens here anyway and get deleted for a number of reasons. So [edit]ing is almost always preferable when clarifying.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you include the gateway addresses of both routers in your question. We have the one at 192.168.2.1 what we don't know is the other routers external address on the 192.168.2.x network (which you should set as static if possible rather than depending on DHCP)

Comment: Also of interest: http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-tables.html

Comment: Especially section 4.8.1. Routing Table Entries (Routes)

Comment: Yes, I realise that trying to obfuscate my network topology wasn't of much. A more detailed graphic is avalaible at [link](http://s21.postimg.org/xmvdl54qf/current_net.jpg)  . Problem is I'd want PC #3 to ssh to PC1 and 2 if possible. R1's routes cannot be modified :-/

Comment: Accordingly to your diagram, you should add the route to PC#3 (the one with IP address 192.168.2.101): `route add -net 10.0.0.0/13 gw 192.168.2.21`.

Comment: @EricCarvalho Please write that up as an answer so we can close this one.

Comment: @user3258184 That is now crystal clear. Thank you.

Comment: It is, and it works. Sorry for all my mumblings earlier. Thanks EricCarvalho and @ElderGeek

Comment: @ElderGeek Done.

Comment: Since it works for you, please upvote/accept the answer to help others with a similar problem to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the route to PC#3 (the one with IP address 192.168.2.101):

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0/13 gw 192.168.2.21
```

Or you can edit your network connection to automatically include a static route when the connection is established (*IPv4 Settings* tab -> *Routes* button):

[image]